# I want to write the contents of row 0 as the column name. What should I do? (pandas columns problem)

Tags: pandas

In the df structure below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koGig.png)

I want to write the contents of row 0 as the column name. What should I do?
The actual number of columns is very large (more than 50)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKE51.png)

Comment: ur post is not clear. could you edit your data a bit better? are you saying you want name, money, time to be the column headers? kindly fix the data you posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help

`header = df.iloc[0]
new_df  = pd.DataFrame(df.values[1:], columns=header)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the input file you read your DataFrame from contained column names
in its first row.
You probably read your DataFrame calling either *read_csv* or *read_fwf*.
Both these functions have *header* parameter, which you probably set to
*None* and in this case:

- column names are created as consecutive numbers, starting from *0*,
- the first row of input file is read as a regular data row.

If I am right, change the way you read your DataFrame.
Maybe it is be enough to remove *header* parameter (its default value
of *infer* is sufficient).